# Lost header in video editing

Tags: interface, edit-mode, video

I'm in the video editor.
I have closed the header by mistake, in the window where you put the videos.

I can't recover it. I need it because it contains "add strip" etc...

What to do to show it again?
Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

[image]

Just click on the tiny drop down arrow to reveal the header again.

Comment: There is no arrow...  I'm in video editing, i restarted the project from the start. But i still can't find a way out. Thanks the same for the answer.